# Need to refresh Access Token using refresh token in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, refresh-token

I have implemented the Oauth2 access token using the JDBC connection everything is working as expected the only problem is when I try to refresh the access token using the refresh token it hits an error.

{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Invalid username or password."
}

```
    package com.oauth2.config;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIENT_ID = "clientID";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "secret";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE = "password, refresh_token";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 15;
    static final int REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 60;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

      JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService = new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);

      if(!jdbcClientDetailsService.listClientDetails().isEmpty() ) {          
      jdbcClientDetailsService.removeClientDetails(CLIENT_ID);     
      }
        configurer
                .jdbc(dataSource)
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password")
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);

    }

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Below is the WebConfigurer file:

```
package com.oauth2.config;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    //@Resource(name = "clientService")
    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll();
    }



    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

//    @Bean
//    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
//        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
//        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
//        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
//        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
//        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
//        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
//        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
//        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
//        bean.setOrder(0);
//        return bean;
//    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to use the refresh_token?

Comment: I am using refresh token as a grant type and sending the refresh_token in the request without the username/password.